# openldap migration - slapd wont start "olcDbDirectory: value #0: invalid path: Permission denied"

Tags: centos7, openldap, slapd

I have migrated my old `slapd` DB to a new server, these are the steps I took:

1. On old server run:

   ```
   slapcat -n 0 -l config.ldif

   slapcat -n 2 -l data.ldif
   ```

   I had to run `slapcat -n 2` because with `-n 1` I get `slapcat: database doesn't support necessary operations.`
2. Copy the two ldif files to new server
3. Install `openldap`:

   ```
   yum install -y openldap openldap-servers openldap-clients
   ```
4. Edit `config.ldif` and change the lines

   ```
   dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
   olcDatabase: {2}bdb
   ```

   to be

   ```
   dn: olcDatabase={1}bdb,cn=config
   olcDatabase: {1}bdb
   ```
5. Run `slapadd` for the two ldif files:

   ```
   slapadd -c -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d -n 0 -l config.ldif
   ```

   First time round this gave me the error about `olcOverlay` not being allowed so I removed the line for the `config.ldif` file then it worked ok.

   ```
   slapadd -c -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d -n 1 -l data.ldif
   ```

   this appeared to work fine.
6. Start `slapd`. This is where my problem is, `slapd` won't start and I get the error:

   ```
   olcDbDirectory: value #0: invalid path: Permission denied
   config error processing olcDatabase={1}bdb,cn=config: olcDbDirectory: value #0: invalid path: Permission denied
   ```

   my `olcDbDirectory` in the `config.ldif` file is set to `/usr/local/openldap/ldap` and this folder exists and is owned by `ldap:ldap` and I've even tried giving it `777` permissions but I still get this error.

I would expect `slapd` to start. If anyone can give me any help it would be amazing, either steps I may have missed or what I should do to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2):

When you import your `config.ldif`, `slapadd` won't overwrite the existing content deployed by the yum installation. To import the configuration correctly, you have to delete the current configuration first:

```bash
rm -r /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config*
sudo -u ldap slapadd -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d -n0 -l config.ldif
```

(If you run `slapadd` as root, then you should `chown -R ldap:ldap /etc/openldap/slapd.d` afterward. `sudo -u ldap` avoids needing to do that.)

If you do it all correctly, `slapadd` will succeed [**without** needing `-c`](https://manpages.debian.org/slapadd.8.en.html#c).